# Deserialization of JSON object with sub field as string using DataContractJsonSerializer in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "Name": "Eli",
    "Age": 4,
    "Children": {
        "Moshe": {
            "Age": 6,
            "Characteristics": "Nice;Good;"
        },
        "Yossi": {
            "Age": 3,
            "Characteristics": "Hero;Brave"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my JSON deserialization function:

```
public static object FromJSON<T>(string json) 
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to serialize it to `Person` object:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Age;

    [DataMember]
    public string Name;

    [DataMember]
    public string Children;
}
```

As you can see, I **do not** want to get `Children` into dictionary but to get it as is - JSON string.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
Person p = (Person)Extensions.FromJSON<Person>(output);
```

And I'm getting exception saying:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type JSONSerialization.Person. End element 'item' from namespace 'item' expected. Found element 'a:item' from namespace 'item'.

**Just to clarify:** I do not want the children sub field to be parsed.

Comment: Maybe its not related, but isn't `Yossi` missing a closing `}` ?

Comment: @bali182 thanks, it was a typo - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the JavaScriptSerializer then you will be able to serialize the Children key into a dynamic field and read it in JSON format if required.

In the `Person` object try and use the `dynamic` type instead of `string` for the `Children` property.

```
public static T FromJavaScriptSerializer<T>(string json)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
    }


public static string ToStringOutput(object dynamicField)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(dynamicField);
}
```

You can use the methods as follows

```
var person = FromJavaScriptSerializer<Person>(output);
Console.WriteLine(ToStringOutput(person.Children));
```

Following will appear in console

> {"Moshe":{"Age":6,"Characteristics":"Nice;Good;"},"Yossi":{"Age":3,"Characteristics":"Hero;Brave"}}

Comment: Not working, I'm getting just an object with no data. Maybe I'm missing something. Can you provide code?

Comment: Thanks.  Whats the difference between your solution to just re-serialize the Children object to json (after de-serializing)??

Comment: If you want to get a string view of the data stored in the dynamic object then you will need to serialize it to a string to view it. The FromJavaScriptSerializer object handles dynamic types better than DataContractJsonSerializer.

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` is better indeed! Especially with dictionaries. Actually now I'm using `Json.Net`, and after de-serializing `Person` I'm re-serializing `Children`...

Answer (score -1):

Use `Regex` to convert `Children` to string (add quotes, replace new lines with \n) before the deserialization https://dotnetfiddle.net/GWs69U

```
string result = Regex.Replace(json, @"(\""Children\""\:(.|\n)*?)(\{(.|\n)*\{(.|\n)*?\}(.|\n)*?\})", (m) =>
{
    return (m.Groups[1] + "\"" + Regex.Replace(m.Groups[3].Value.Replace("\n", " "), @"\s+", " ") + "\"");
});
```

Comment: I'm preferring not to do so. I already could just re-serialize the `Children` object to json (after deserializing) instead..

Comment: Regex should always be a last ditch option, after all other options have been considered.